# JDatePicker jar can't find local en_GB?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, locale

I have an error when I tried to use `java.util.Locale` in eclipse project:

> $Can't find bundle for base name i18n, locale en_GB

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Can't find bundle for base name i18n, locale en_GB at 
java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name i18n, locale en_GB
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hi there! I edited your question title to be more clear about what your problem is and I edited the error from your post into the question itself. Try to edit the question to add additional or new information, rather than posting it as comments where people might miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is it getting `en_GB` from?

Locales in Java use dashes, not underscores (i.e. `en-GB`).

See [Java 8 supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html) for the full list.